# Прибавление единицы раз в сутки?

Tags: php, modx

Раз в сутки число увеличивается на 1 и дробится на каждое число, но число почемуто не увеличивается. В чем моя ошибка:

```
$count = (floor( time() / 86400) - 16375) * 1 + 5640;

$countarr = str_split($count);

foreach ($countarr as $value) {
    echo '<span>'.$value.'</span>';
}
```

Comment: А где у вас оператор сложения для цифры `1`? Насколько я хорошо помню арифметику, то умножение числа на 1 всегда возвращает исходное число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно я понял, то:

- `16375` — количество дней, прошедших, начиная с 1 января 1970, до сегодняшнего дня, но это число сейчас будет равно `17742`, так как ваше число - это количество дней, подсчитанное годами ранее.
- `5640` — число, к которому будет прибавляться единица, следовательно, завтра уже должно быть `5641`.

Вот, думаю так будет выглядеть правильнее:

```
$count = (floor( time() / 86400) - 17742) * 1 + 5640;

print_r(str_split($count));
```

В результате получим:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 0
)
```

Comment: Видимо проблема в чем, то другом. Число на сайте не меняется по прошествии 24 часов